# How do I open WinSCP GUI from command line and log into a server

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments, command-prompt, winscp

I need an equivalent to what

```
putty.exe -ssh <IPAddress>:<Port>
```

would do. What the above command does is open up PuTTY and asks for the servers credentials. I would like to have the equivalent for WinSCP. I searched around the internet and understood the command line WinSCP arguments and how to open a scripting interface. But what I really want is a GUI interface to open up.

Why do I want it this way? Because I have an application which has a button. When I click that button, it should open up WinSCP for that server and ask for the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is:

```
winscp.exe sftp://<IPAddress>:<Port>
```

For details see:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url